# main thread waits for threads in the finalize c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to have the main thread spawn threads and be able to keep spawning more with out waiting for all of the threads to finish. The spawning of the threads is user controlled, so the user could add at different periods of time more threads.

The thing is... how can I do this, when the main thread is running the finalize. In the finalize make it wait until all active threads have finished.

Comment: is this about proper use of .join() method?

Comment: There's something missing from your question: you said that the user can add threads at different periods of time. My question is: what will the main thread do while waiting for the user? How will the main thread know that the user has no more threads to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep track of all your created threads; for example, through a `List<Thread>` collection. When you’re in your `finalize` method, just iterate over all your threads and call their `Join` method sequentially, as shown in the `WaitForThreads` method below:

```
private readonly List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

public void SpawnThread(Action action)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(action));
    thread.IsBackground = false;
    threads.Add(thread);
    thread.Start();
}

private void WaitForThreads()
{
    foreach (Thread thread in threads)
        thread.Join();
}
```

[`Thread.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx) blocks the calling thread (which should be your main thread) until the specific thread terminates. If the thread was already terminated, then the call would return immediately (which is why you don’t really need to remove threads from the collection upon termination, although you still should for the sake of garbage collection).

Also, you should consider *why* you need to wait for the threads to terminate within your `finalize` method. If it’s simply to prevent them from being forcibly aborted when your main thread terminates, then there’s no need; your process would remain alive (even without a window) until all threads whose [`IsBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) property is `false` finish executing. Similarly for garbage collection; your heap objects will not get finalized until they’re no longer referenced from *any* live thread, not just the main.

Comment: I really don't need the Thread.Join since I don't require any returns from the threads. All I need is to have the main thread ready to receive more and more threads while the spawned threads do the work.

This is so funny the code that I have works fine. What I was missing was the IsBackground=false; line. I had this in true so when ever the main thread terminated the spawned threads went with it.

Comment: The use of the term “background” in this context is misleading. It is common for developers to initially assume that all threads are background threads except for the main one. Glad to have helped!